# How to make django-filter depend on another django-filter

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm using package django-filter and i have some fields which i want to be depend on another field like i have field `name` and field `car` and if i choose name Michael in `name` filter, filter `car` will show me only cars that Michael has

This looks like a big problem and i dont know how to solve that

filters.py

```
import django_filters

from django_filters import DateTimeFromToRangeFilter

from django.db.models import Q

from common.filters import CustomDateRangeWidget
from common.models import CounterParty, ObjectList

from .models import OpenPointList


class OpenPointFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    """
    Django-filter class to filter OpenPointList model by date, CounterParty name and Object name
    """

    CHOICES = (
        ('Closed', 'Closed'),
        ('Open', 'Open')
    )

    status = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=CHOICES)


    category_choice = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(label='Категория',
                                                       queryset=OpenPointList.objects.values_list('category',
                                                                                                  flat=True).distinct())

    category = django_filters.CharFilter(method='custom_category_filter')

    class Meta:
        model = OpenPointList
        fields = (
            'open_point_object',
            'status',
            'category',
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Ajax for this, like when you select one dropdown then you have to call Ajax and in response, you have to set options in another dropdown and so on.